# stuck on for loop using pivot_wider or reshape in r for specific columns

Tags: r, function, for-loop, reshape

I wrote a previous question on how to transpose rows into columns which has helped in my work but my 2nd additional question and issue is that I'm trying to transpose rows into columns for 120 columns and with different column names.

For example:

I have rows in columns that are called "Initial_Event_User_Field_Label_01", "Initial_Event_User_Field_Label_02" and the values are in columns that are called "Initial_Event_User_Field_01", "Initial_Event_User_Field_02".

| Initial_Event_User_Field_Label_01 | Initial_Event_User_Field_01 | Initial_Event_User_Field_Label_02 | Initial_Event_Field_02 | Additional_Asset_User_Field_Label_01 | Additional_Asset_User_Field_01 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Age | 4 |  |  | Position | S |
| Start Date | 2020-04-04 | Number | 46 |  |  |
|  |  | Location | AL | Identifier | Yes |

This goes on for 30 columns and then I have another set of 30 columns that are titled "Interest_Asset_User_Field_Label_01" and "Interest_Asset_User_Field_01.
As you can see I'm transposing over 100+ columns and am trying to figured out how I can conduct some type of for loop that identifies if the column name has a string called "Field_Label_" + a # to then transpose it with the next round of "Field_" + #.

```
for (i in colnames(active) %in% "Field_Label_"){
  if(colnames(active) %in% "Field_Label_" + i){
    active %>%
      mutate(row = Row_number()) %>%
      pivot_wider(names_from = (colnames(active) %in% "Field_Label_" + i), values_from =
                    (colnames(active) %in% "Field_" + i)) %>%
      select(-row)}
  break
}
```

Code above was me just trying to figure out how to write or go about this. I was wondering if the approach should be just through the code above and only using a for loop and an if statement or should I try to build a function (** my attempt to build a function below**) - also still learning on how functions are built and was trying to put down into syntax what I'm trying to complete:

```
transpose_cols <- function(df, col_str, val_str, col_val, val_num) {
  for (i in colnames(df)){
  if(colnames(df) %in% col_str+val_str){
     df <- spread(df, key = col_str+val_str, value = val_num+i)
  }
    break
  }
}
```

Comment: Given this sample data, what is your eventual expected output? You will likely need to make an expected-output frame *manually*, but knowing what columns should be there and the values from the current sample is a good start. Thanks!

Comment: Hi! The expected output is to have the current dataset above transposed so that each category (Age, Start Date) become columns and the values from Initial_Event_User_Field_01 would become the values to each respective category. When you say to make an expected output frame manually what do you mean exactly?

Comment: It is far better (unambiguous) to *show* expected output given this sample data. Manually, I mean `data.frame(Age = c(...), Start = c(...), Date = c(...), ...)`. Perhaps forming it in Excel or Calc and posting the CSV of it. Perhaps something else.